# Moving the view's axis for rotation programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I am rotating my View using SetRotationX. However, since this is a scroll view, I want the rotation to always be performed on the visible part of the screen (the middle of it). The default behavior is to rotate it around the middle of the view, which sometimes is out of screen.
I've noticed the "transformPivotX" property, but I'm creating my view on the fly, not from the resources.
Does anyone know how to do it (programmatically)?

Thanks,
yakobom

Answer (score 1):

OK, that was stupid... I dont know how I missed it. It's "SetPivotX"...